# Unexpected result of java calculation

Tags: java

Why does the following code:

`System.out.println((int)(19.99 * 100));`

produce the result "1998"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rounding errors. If you look at the result of your calculation without the cast, you get:

```
1998.9999999999998
```

So when you cast to int, the decimal part is dropped, not rounded up, and you get 1998.

The moral is, if you need an exact answer, don't use float / double at all. If you're talking about a discrete value like money, use int and deal with the atomic unit (eg. pence.) If you do need exact decimals, then `BigDecimal` is your friend.

While you can bodge the result here using `Math.round()` to bring the result to where it's expected, this won't work in all cases and fails to address the underlying issue.

Comment: I don't think this addresses the real issue, which is the inability to represent 19.99 accurately

Comment: @BrianAgnew I've added a bit now to address that.

Answer (score 5):

That is because 19.99 cannot be represented exactly.

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(19.99));
```

prints the value this actually represents which is the closest to 19.99 it can represent.

```
19.989999999999998436805981327779591083526611328125
```

and `19.99 * 100` is

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(19.99 * 100));
```

which is

```
1998.999999999999772626324556767940521240234375
```

The problem is that you have a representation error in 19.99 which is still there when multiplied by 100 you get a number which is slightly too small.

if you multiply by 100 and **round down** which is what `(int)` does you should expect to get 1998.

An alternative is

```
System.out.println(Math.round(19.99 * 100));
```

Comment: Whilst that is true, that reason would not explain the returning of 1998, 19.99 * 100 is 1999.

Comment: I think this answer addresses the *fundamentals* of this issue. +1

Comment: @SeanKenny I don't follow. `1998.9999999999998436805981327779591083526611328125` rounded down is `1998`?

Comment: @SeanKenny 19.99 * 100 is not 1999 as a double. I don't see how I can make it any clearer

Comment: I added that comment before you edited your answer. Your edit clarified what you meant.

Comment: @SeanKenny Well 5 people agreed with you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

because the calculation of 19.99 * 100 will result in 1998.999999 and you are casting it to int it will discard the fractional part of it.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to a rounding issues. `double` and  `float` are prone to these issues, which is why it is recommended you use the [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class.

This code should print what is expected:

```
BigDecimal bg = new BigDecimal("19.99");
System.out.println(bg.multiply(new BigDecimal("10")));
```

This yields:

`199.90`

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println((19.99 * 100));
```

produces the result 1998.9999999999998 by adding **int** casting it truncates the fraction part and returns 1998

Answer (score 1):

Floating point data types (float and double in Java) can only approximately represent most decimal values. See [Joshua Bloch's](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PA218&ots=yYGjKjq6NY&dq=josh%20bloch%20float&pg=PA218#v=onepage&q=josh%20bloch%20float&f=false) words of wisdom on the subject for more details.